# "Master PostgreSQL identifier is not matching with Slave PostgreSQL identifier" error while trying the PostgreSQL master-slave WAL replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.2

I am trying the PostgreSQL-9.2 master to slave replication (through WAL log files)  between a windows server (Master) and Windows machine (Slave).

Getting the error saying:

> Master PostgreSQL identifier is not matching with Slave PostgreSQL identifier

However, when I try the Master-Slave replication between two machines, I can replicate the data between them.

How can I debug/fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The slave has to be initialized with a physical backup of the master. Use `pg_basebackup` for the initial copy.